# Deleting outputPath in cascading

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

We generally delete the output path in mapreduce by using the following code

```
outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath,true);
```

My question is, can we do the same in cascading? If yes please suggest me the steps for doing so.
Thankyou:)

Comment: What do you mean by cascading?

Comment: Its an API over hadoop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the intent is to reuse the output directory for next run of mapreduce then set the property of your sink Tap to SinkMode.REPLACE. It deletes the hdfs output DIR and mapreduce jobs will not fails between re runs.

```
Tap sink = new Hfs(<your scheme>,<your output hdfs dir>,SinkMode.REPLACE)
```

Comment: Okay but you need to wait for a while

Comment: Yes! Its working. Actually I am not using Gradle. I am directly running it over linux in a cluster